# How to do a GET on a PHP page to get a JSON object?

Tags: php, jquery

How do I accomplish the following:
User clicks on "Start" button on an HTML page makes a GET to a getnumber.php page, that returns the number 10 in the following form: {count: 10}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//you jquery code
$.getJSON('getnumber.php', function(data) {
  alert(data); //returns your json_encoded number sent from getnumber.php page
});

//your php page
$arr = array("count" => 10);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" id="btnID"/>

$("#btnID").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default behavior of the button, or return false as @alecgorge pointed it out
$.get("process.php",function(data){
console.log(data);
},'json');  //<-- specifying the dataType as json will parse the json return by the server
});
```

in the process.php

```
var $count=10;
echo json_encode($count);
```

look at

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

[$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: probably want a `return false;` at the end of click event.

Answer (score 0):

Try Google.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_intro.asp) is a good place to start.
[Then go here](http://www.json.org/) and learn more.
Put them together and you should be well on your way.

Answer (score 0):

use `json_decode` in `getnumber.php`

[json decode manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need PHP return data in JSON format, which would be:

```
{"count": 10}
```

and indicating the returning data is JSON format with a header in the response.

From JavaScript side the returned value, the previous string, can be evalutated and converted to a JS object.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$.get('getnumber.php', function(data) {
   var result = eval(data);
});
```

If the page getnumber.php output {count: 10} then you get the result with result.count

You can also use $.getJSON method.